# Getting a seg fault when tokenizing string in c

Tags: c

I just started programming in C a few days ago. My program opens a file, reads it line by line then removes stuff I don't need (brackets, newline,etc..), then once I just have the data in a comma separated format I want to add it to an array(then add that array to a array of arrays).  I'm at the point where I am tokenize the comma separated string but I keep getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.` when I run it in debugger.

What am I doing wrong? Here's the section of my code that is giving me the problem:

```
//now data(variable: line) looks like this:  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4
char *str_ptr;
str_ptr = strtok(line, ",");
  for(; str_ptr != NULL ;){
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", str_ptr);
    str_ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
  }
```

Here's my entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char line[1024];
    FILE *fp = fopen("/Users/me/Desktop/output.txt","r");

    printf("Starting.. \n");
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        return 1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    int list[30]; //items will be stored here

    while(fgets(line, 1024, fp) != EOF) {
        count++;
        //parse the text in the line Remove the open bracket, then remove the last newline,comma and close bracket
        // data looks like this: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4],
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        memmove(line, line+1, len-4);
        line[len-4] = 0;
        printf("%s \n",line);

        //parse the numbers in the char
        //now data looks like this:  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4
        char *str_ptr;
        str_ptr = strtok(line, ",");
          for(; str_ptr != NULL ;){
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", str_ptr);
            str_ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
          }


        //for testing just stop the file after two lines
        if (count == 2) {
            break;
        }

        
        if ( count > 1000000) {
            printf("count is higher than 1,000,000 \n");
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    printf(" num of lines is %i \n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Other than the debugger I'm not sure how to get meaningful information in this case.

### Update

Sorry, didn't know how to do this. Here is a copy of the stack in the debugger (other than main, if I click on them they all say "No source available for .." then the items in the list:

```
Thread [1] (Suspended : Signal : EXC_BAD_ACCESS:Could not access memory)    
    strlen() at 0x7fff875ef4f0  
    __vfprintf() at 0x7fff875908c3  
    vfprintf_l() at 0x7fff8758f18e  
    fprintf() at 0x7fff87598d9a 
    main() at learningC.c:77 0x100000d5a
```

Comment: What line do you get the segfault on?

Comment: @interjay I didn't realize I get this error multiple times.  I posted the stack from the debugger. Is it helpful or is there some other information I can get?

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` returns a `NULL` on error or EOF. Check for that not for `EOF`.

```
while(fgets(line, 1024, fp) != NULL){
```

Comment: I still get the same problem.  If I comment out part when I try to tokenize the char then the program completes, but when I add it thats when it ends early.

Comment: It ran just fine (with little modifications of your code) here: http://ideone.com/aQY2g

Comment: It will still fail on lines shorter than 4;

Comment: Thanks Thurstmaster..Other than what you wrote above was there anything else you changed? I read my code and yours and it seemed the same, yet I get these errors.  @wildplasser I am not sure if it'll matter because the number of items I want to add to the list is always take same(30)

Comment: @wildplasser: Yes, that could happen when fgets reaches EOF yet it continues because of bad while condition.
@Error_404: No, only other change I did was to use stdin, and comment out the `return 1;`

Comment: Its really weird, you code looks the same but I ran it and it just reads the file but doesn't have any output while the file is being read(the file is massive 20+gb). When I was testing this before, it was reading/outputing one line at a time, the structure seems to be the same but its not doing it. I'm using a mac, is there a difference between C compilers on different systems(i.e. should I be doing this on linux instead)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong if the input file is always valid. I tried to compile and run it on my Mac and it's working really fine. Maybe you can upload sample file somewhere so we can see what's going on exactly, because the code in `memmove` part is too vulnerable for the invalid input (blank line or short line for example). I would suggest to change it to

```
char* data = line;
size_t len = strlen(line);
if (len > 3) {
    line[len - 3] = '\0';
    data++;
}

char *str_ptr;
str_ptr = strtok(data, ",");
for(; str_ptr != NULL ;){
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", str_ptr);
    str_ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

My code is still far from perfect data validation, but at least it won't throw seg fault on blank line.